# Definition on Touch Gestures

Tags: touch, gestures

Are there any non-platform specific definitions of touch gestures, that are typically used for devices like Android or iPhone.

I'm trying to write a specification for a multi-platform product that uses touch gestures. However, people have different opinions (depending on the platform they come from) what each gesture means.

So I was wondering if there is any "standard" definition on touch gestures. On Wikipedia [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-touch_gestures) is the best I could find. But I'm sure people who are working on academic UI research must have some standard definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be of use - [Open Source Gesture Library](http://gestureworks.com/features/open-source-gestures/)

Comment: I assume that link once pointed to the same resource as [GestureML wiki](http://www.gestureml.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) does now.

Comment: @Crissov Neither of these links are still working... Now it is maybe somewhere like http://gestureml.org/doku.php/gestures

Answer (score 3):

Tailor your gestures to the platform you are using. Users are already familiar with the the gestures of the platform, so use the same in your specification.

iPhone and Android both have resources for their standard gestures.

And this guide might be a good place to start:
http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1071

Comment: I was emphasizing on a non-platform specific definition, because we're building a multi-platform solution and we're not developing standard gestures. It was more about using common names.

Answer (score 1):

The Dan Saffer book ["Designing Gestural Interfaces"](http://www.designinggesturalinterfaces.com/) is probably relevant.

Comment: hint: this link is not working anymore. I think you can read it here https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/designing-gestural-interfaces/9780596156756/ch01.html